# CSS working in IE, but not FF

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple css file for my Asp.Net MVC application.

```
    body
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: x-small;
    color: #663300;
}

input
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: x-small;
    background-color: #FFFF99;
    color: #CC6600;
    border: 1px solid #808000;
}
.headerRow
{
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    border-style: none none dotted none;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #800000;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: x-small;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

The Body is working well in both... as is the input. However, the headerRow isn't working in FF, yet works well in IE.

Here it is, being used:

```
 <table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tr class="headerRow">
        <td>
            Transaction Date
        </td>
        <td>
            Type
        </td>

        <td>
            Category
        </td>
        <td>
            Budget Assignment
        </td>
        <td>
            Cost Center
        </td>
        <td align="right">

            Amount
        </td>
    </tr>
```

The header row just displays as normal body text though...

Comment: Sorry - the formatting of the CSS wasn't handled well with StackOverflow. Hope it's understandable.

Comment: There, its a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try condensing your code a little. For example:

`.headerRow { border-bottom: solid 1px #800000; }`

would save you three lines worth of code. Could you also elaborate on what is not working? Border? All styles associated with headerRow?

Comment: Check this: http://www.budgiemoney.com/budgiemoney/BankAccount/Transactions Looks at it in both Firefox and IE... It seems the cell formatting isn't working in Firefox. (Dummy data displayed)

Comment: Hang on!! CTRL+F5 seemed to fix it! Looks like the browser had cached the CSS or something? It'ds working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your CSS and HTML codes with this validator ?

http://validator.w3.org/ -> html
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ -> css

Comment: It all seems fine. Those sites say it's fine.